# Simulating keypress with mouse movement using DirectInput (dinput.dll)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, directinput

I have been trying to play Omikron: The Nomad Soul, but I found it incredibly difficult to do so without using the mouse. I have been trying to use dinput.dll to simulate keyboard presses using mouse movement, but nothing I tried so far worked. I am a complete amateur at this, so I thought I should ask how to do this properly.

What I am trying to do is to edit dinput.dll source code from github, create a dinput.dll file with configurable ini file, where you can assign key presses to mouse movement. This would be beneficial in many old games.

For example;
Mouse moving up = press up arrow key

Mouse moving down = press down arrow key

Mouse moving left = press left arrow key

Mouse moving right = press right arrow key

Reason why I want to use dinput instead of something like autohotkey is because stuff like autohotkey doesn't always get along well with old games. For example Omikron: The Nomad Soul.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You should start from somewhere, we can't make it for you... There is no "proper" way

Comment: As I mentioned, I did start with the source code of dinput.dll. I have been trying to do this for ages. I just don't know how. I can usually figure out how to implement it when I find out what code to use, but dinput is ancient and nothing I tried had any decent results. Whenever I find code that's supposed to accomplish this, it just doesn't mash with dinput.dll code.

And there is always a "proper" way to do it. If there wasn't, everyone would always do a perfect job.